# hasClass not rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using the Marketpress plugin in Wordpress that has been customized to allow multiple items to be added to the cart with a single click. My problem is on this [page](http://simplygreatresumes.minnebyte.com/job-seekers-add-on-services/)

The 'add to cart' button displays in Chrome just fine, but fails to display in IE. I believe the problem is in this area

```
if($(".mp_button_addcart").length){
    if($('body').hasClass('page-id-1563') || $('body').hasClass('page-id-391')){
        console.log('show');
        $('.page-bkp-frame').last().append('<input style="display:block" class="total_adddcart" type="button" name="addcart" value="Add To Cart >>" onclick="javascript:addcart_all();" >');
    }else{
        $('.mp_button_addcart').show();
        $('.chk-addcart').remove();
        $('.mp_buy_form').attr('style', '');
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know this is the problem but it should be `if($(".mp_button_addcart").length > 0){`.

Comment: This fiddle works in IE7-9: http://jsfiddle.net/tvG9G/

Comment: @jSang `.length` can only be non-negative int, [ToBoolean](http://es5.github.com/x9.html#x9.2) of any int other than `0` or `NaN` is `true`, hence `> 0` in this case is unnecessary.

Comment: My apologies. If you go to http://simplygreatresumes.minnebyte.com/job-seekers-add-on-services/ in chrome you will notice an 'add to cart' button towards the bottom of the screen. The same button will not display in IE.

Comment: Did my idea of setting a `cancelSave` flag not seem appealing?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using currently?
Because certain functionality in IE 8 doesn't seem to be working fine. Try with IE 9 and see. It may work. Because your code seems to be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.log(); will kill jQuery in many cases in IE. try commenting that out. Might do the trick. You can test the theory by hitting F12, and reloading. If it works then, console.log is the problem.

Comment: my pleasure. This has caused me so much trouble too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case then you can try this approach.. Not the best approach though..

```
var $body = $('body');

var classNames = $body.prop('class');

if( classNames.indexOf('page-id-1563') > -1 
                                     || classNames.indexOf('page-id-391') > -1){
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sushanth I appreciate your help, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(jQuery(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked') == 'checked'){
```

to

```
if (jQuery(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
```